# What's the point of Voldemort having followers?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Voldemort seems obsessed with himself, wanting power and escaping death. He wants to be the most knowledgeable, most powerful, most immortal, wizard to ever be. He is also a psychopath. He does not seem to be like Grindelwald in his motivations, but then ends up using the means that seem appropriate for Grindelwalds motivation. Contrary to how Grindelwald is portrayed in the books, people are simply tools for Voldemort. His world domination trip seems counter-productive or at least somewhat orthogonal to his other goals.

Why does he go on a world domination trip, recruit followers, etc. when what I think what his motivation is could simply be achieved by locking himself in an ivory tower?

Comment: I kind of agree with you, but I would also argue that there is more than one form of power. Powerful magic is one thing; power over people is another. But note that contrary to other dark mages, and other big bad guys in other novels, Voldemort really only has followers, no real generals and certainly not advisors. Bellatrix Lestrange fancies herself to be his closest ally, but even her is really not that close to him.

Comment: Voldemort is a _very_ powerful magician. But only _one_. Without support, all the other magicians could take him out quite easily. Especially with those who are now his followers joining the fight against him as well.

Comment: @gnasher729 Well yes, but the main reason they fight him is because of his world domination ambitions.